How does a non-zero slow roll parameter break the conformal invariance of the kinetic term in the scalar Lagrangian?
I am trying to understand how the introduction of a non-zero slow roll parameter ($\epsilon$) breaks the conformal invariance of the kinetic term in the scalar Lagrangian, particularly in the context of inflationary cosmology. Here is the background of my thought process:
Starting from de Sitter space, which is characterized by an exponential expansion, the metric in conformal time $\eta$ can be written as:
$$ ds^2 = \frac{1}{H^2 \eta^2} \left( d\eta^2 - d\vec{x}^2 \right)$$
During inflation, the expansion is not exactly exponential but close to it. The slow roll parameter $\epsilon$ quantifies the deviation from the exact de Sitter case. The metric with a non-zero slow roll parameter is given by:
$$ ds^2 = \frac{1}{H^2 \eta^2 (1 - \epsilon)^2} \left( d\eta^2 - d\vec{x}^2 \right)$$
In the context of scalar field theory, the Lagrangian for a scalar field $\phi$ in this spacetime is:
$$ \mathcal{L} = \sqrt{-g} \left( \frac{1}{2} \partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi \right) $$
Under a conformal transformation, the scalar field transforms as:
$$ \delta_\lambda \phi = \lambda (\phi' + \nabla \phi) $$
$$ \delta_b \phi = 2 \vec{b} \cdot \vec{x} (\phi' + \nabla \phi) + (\eta^2 - x^2) \vec{b} \cdot \nabla \phi $$
I have attempted to derive how the slow roll parameter affects the conformal invariance. Here is my derivation:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\delta \mathcal{L} &= \frac{\sqrt{-g}}{2} \delta (\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi) = \sqrt{-g} \partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu (\delta \phi) \\\\
&= \partial_\mu \left( \sqrt{-g} \partial^\mu \phi \delta \phi \right) - \partial_\mu \left( \sqrt{-g} \partial^\mu \phi \right) \delta \phi
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
The integral of first term would depend on the boundary where $\delta\phi$ vanishes and the second term is zero by the virtue of equation of motion of scalar field. I expected from this that kinetic term would be invariant regardless of the transformation. However, according to the paper by Baumann titled "High-Scale Inflation and the Tensor Tilt". The scalar field Lagrangian in the given metric is:
$$ \mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{H^4 \eta^4 (1 - \epsilon)^4} \left( \frac{1}{2} (H^2 \eta^2 (1 - \epsilon)^2 \partial_\eta \phi \partial_\eta \phi - H^2 \eta^2 (1 - \epsilon)^2 \nabla \phi \nabla \phi) \right) $$
which simplifies to:
$$ \mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} \left( (\partial_\eta \phi)^2 - (\nabla \phi)^2 \right) \frac{1}{H^2 \eta^2 (1 - \epsilon)^2} $$
Under conformal transformation, the variation of the Lagrangian is:
\begin{equation}\label{eq}
\delta \mathcal{L} = \lambda \epsilon \left( (\partial_\eta \phi)^2 - (\nabla \phi)^2 \right)\tag{1}
\end{equation}
It is easier to see that setting $\epsilon = 0$ restores conformal symmetry as it corresponds to the exact de Sitter spacetime. However, with $\epsilon \neq 0$, the conformal invariance is broken.
This result indicates that the kinetic term is no longer invariant under conformal transformations when $\epsilon$ is non-zero. The major issue I am facing in my understanding is how to derive this result.
My question is: How does the non-zero slow roll parameter $\epsilon$ specifically lead to the breaking of conformal invariance of the kinetic term in the scalar Lagrangian i.e. How to derive the equation \eqref{eq} and how can this be understood more intuitively in the context of inflationary cosmology?

Intuitively, de Sitter is one of three maximally symmetric spacetimes (determined by the sign of the cosmological constant), so any deviation from de Sitter must break some symmetries. Conformal invariance is very hard to maintain because it's very easy to introduce a scale into the problem. In this case, the slow roll scalar field introduces a "clock" into de Sitter -- you can distinguish different times based on the potential energy of the scalar field -- and the rate of change of the scalar field introduces a scale that inevitably breaks conformal invariance. Since the kinetic term depends on the scale factor, and the time evolution of the scalar field affects the scale factor, it is not surprising that you can see the breaking of conformal invariance in the kinetic term.
To derive A.5 and A.6, you plug A.2 and A.3 into A.4 and simplify. You will need to use integration by parts. It's probably a good idea to check that if you plug A.2 and A.3 into A.1, you get the expected conformal invariance, before checking what happens in the more complicated case where conformal invariance is broken.

I tried doing the same thing but I am unable to arrive at the final result
